# What is Control's DesignMode property and how to use it?

Tags: c#, asp.net

what is DesignMode property? When it is useful? I don't understand it from msdn definition http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.designmode.aspx

Some example? Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The DesignMode property will be set to True when you are editing your asp.net page in Visual Studio.
For example if you create a chart control you could show a chart based on dummy data during design-time and at run-time generate a chart based on the provided data.

Answer (score 1):

This is a property that let's you know if you are running in Visual Studio Designer. It is helpful when you are writing a custom control and you want it to behave differently during design time.

Answer (score 1):

One example of when you might use `DesignMode` is for design time specific behavior, for instance is when creating a custom control and you want to set its display text equal to the name of the control:

```
if (DesignMode && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
  Text = Name;
```